# Plot Effects of Variables in Interaction Terms

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, interaction, plm

I would like to plot the effects of variables in interaction terms, using panel data and a FE model.

I have various interaction effects in my equation, for example this one here:

```
FIXED1 <- plm(GDPPCgrowth ~ FDI * PRIVCR, data = dfp)
```

I can only find solutions for lm, but not for plm.

So on the x-axis there should be PRIVCR and on the y-axis the effect of FDI on growth.

Thank you for your help!

Lisa

Comment: You should try to include a reproducible example in your post. As it is, we can't run your code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a package that supports `plm` objects directly. As you are asking for FE models, you can just take an LSDV approach for FE and do the estimation by `lm` to get an lm object which works with the `effects` package. Here is an example for the Grunfeld data:

```
library(plm)
library(effects)
data("Grunfeld", package = "plm")

mod_fe <- plm(inv ~ value + capital + value:capital, data = Grunfeld, model = "within")
Grunfeld[ , "firm"] <- factor(Grunfeld[ , "firm"]) # needs to be factor in the data NOT in the formula [required by package effects]
mod_lsdv <- lm(inv ~ value + capital + value:capital + firm, data = Grunfeld)
coefficients(mod_fe)    # estimates are the same
coefficients(mod_lsdv)  # estimates are the same

eff_obj <- effects::Effect(c("value", "capital"), mod_lsdv)
plot(eff_obj)
```